# How to store a function pointer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, function, pointers

Let's say I want to store a group of function pointers in a `List<(*func)>`, and then later call them, perhaps even with parameters... Like if I stored in a `Dict<(*func), object[] params>` could I call the func with the parameters?  How would I do this?

Comment: Dict<(*func), object[] params> looks like a bad idea but that's just me.

Comment: I use it to "switch" on types, using the Type as the key and the function as the code.  Works great where "switch(typeof(string))" wouldn't...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

.NET uses delegates instead of function pointers. You can store a delegate instance like any other kind of object, in a dictionary or otherwise.

See [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) from the C# Programming Guide on MSDN.

Answer (score 22):

You can absolutely have a dictionary of functions:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<T>> actionList = new Dictionary<string, Action<T>>();
Dictionary<string, Func<string>> functionList = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>();

actionList.Add("firstFunction", ()=>{/*do something;*/});
functionList.Add("firstFunction", ()=>{return "it's a string!";});
```

You can then call the methods like this:

```
string s = functionList["firstFunction"].Invoke();
```

Comment: You can also call them directly: `functionList["firstFunction"]()`

Answer (score 8):

Look at the C# documentation on delegates, which is the C# equivalent of a function pointer (it may be a plain function pointer or be curried once to supply the this parameter).  There is a lot of information that will be useful to you.

Comment: Which C# documentation on delegates? Links would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you could do this.  You could do it as others have suggested through the use of delegates.  But to get the dictionary to work, they would all need the same signature.

```
var funcs = new Dictionary<Action<object[]>, object[]>();
```

Or if they have different signatures you could use the actual reflected method, like the following

```
var funcs = new Dictionary<MethodInfo, object[]>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ether a delegate or an event (depending on the usage).

Comment: How can you store an event in a collection?

Comment: @svick, Event properties downy have get and set, they have add and remove, because events keep a list of handlers.

Answer (score -1):

If you are only storing event handlers then...

```
Dictionary<string, EventHandler> dictEvents = new Dictionary<string, EventHandler>();
dictEvents.Add("Event1", someEventHandler);

...

protected void someEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do something.
}
```

Edit:

- I put this here because I was searching for a way to do something similar when I found this post. However, the solutions in this post did not quite work for my situation so I figured I would share what did work for me.

Comment: What makes you think the question is about event handlers?