# How to specify Generic types on delegates?

Tags: vb.net, generics

Maybe I am just not reading the MSDN documentation correctly, but given a function that takes in one string parameter and returns type T, how can this be specifed as a shared function using Func()?

MSDN says `Func(Of In T1, Out TResult)`, but all of their examples use the same data type, i.e., `Func(Of String, String)`.  I want to do `Func(Of In String, Out T)`, where T is arbitrary (but I can constrain it if necessary by a base class).  I want it shared/static at the class level, yet the encapsulating class will itself not be a generic class.  It seems in this specific scenario, it's impossible to do what I want because the compiler would have no way of knowing what Type T is at runtime.

So is it possible to do generics on delegates or anonymous lambda expressions in VB.net (not C#)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. You can certainly use generic delegate types within a generic method or type. As a trivial example:

```
public T Convert<T>(Func<string, T> converter, string text)
{
    return converter(text);
}
```

However, you can't do this without `T` being a type parameter itself, specified either in the generic method or type.

Comment: Got that in VB.net form?  Despite being somewhat schooled in C, I find it difficult to read C# for some odd reason.

Comment: And yeah, I should add, encapsulated within a method, I could probably do what I want.  I'm thinking something more along the like of creating a dictionary of delegates, per this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550218/how-to-store-a-function-pointer-in-c

Comment: Mostly because I'm trying to find a better way for avoiding large `Select Case ...` statements when I need to determine what type an object is at runtime.  I've ran into references of using polymorphism to do that instead of large conditional blocks.  Hard part is finding a decent example of such.