# C# function pointer?

Tags: c#, pointers, methods

I'm having a problem with C#, I'd like to get a pointer of a method in my code, but it seems impossible. I need the pointer of the method because I want to no-op it using WriteProcessMemory. How would I get the pointer?

Example code

```
main()
{
    function1();
    function2();
}

function1()
{
    //get function2 pointer
    //use WPM to nop it (I know how, this is not the problem)
}
function2()
{
    Writeline("bla"); //this will never happen because I added a no-op.
}
```

Comment: That isn't a valid C# code. what are you trying to do?

Comment: seems similar (very) to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550218/how-to-store-a-function-pointer-in-c-sharp). it might also help you.

Comment: You are approaching the problem in the (totally) wrong way. Why do you want to no-op the method? You can do that – but differently, depending on your calling code.

Comment: Since C# is a JITted language, the code for the function may not exist at the time you ask. Your patching may also interfere with the CLR, since it also plays funny games in order to do GC. Instead of patching, use the debugging API.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to hack something. Assuming that you are not doing something illegal, C++ is the better language for such low level hacks.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes I'm not hacking anything. I'm working with a modding api on a game. I need to edit a method of the game which cannot be accessed via the api. So instead of editing I could nop it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Actually you can with Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate, (which is internally used during the PInvoke mechanism so you can get callbacks into C# from unmanaged code) - this forces a JIT of the method if it's not already compiled. But that's besides the point. What user1276333 is doing is a bad idea - the JITted code is unpredicable and should never be messed with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a function pointer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550218/how-to-store-a-function-pointer-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 47):

I know this is very old, but an example of something like a function pointer in C# would be like this:

```cs
class Temp 
{
   public void DoSomething() {}
   public void DoSomethingElse() {}
   public void DoSomethingWithAString(string myString) {}
   public bool GetANewCat(string name) { return true; }
}
```

...and then in your main or wherever:

```
var temp = new Temp();
Action myPointer = null, myPointer2 = null;
myPointer = temp.DoSomething;
myPointer2 = temp.DoSomethingElse;
```

Then to call the original function,

```
myPointer();
myPointer2();
```

If you have arguments to your methods, then it's as simple as adding generic arguments to your Action:

```
Action<string> doItWithAString = null;
doItWithAString = temp.DoSomethingWithAString;

doItWithAString("help me");
```

Or if you need to return a value:

```
Func<string, bool> getACat = null;
getACat = temp.GetANewCat;

var gotIt = getACat("help me");
```

Comment: Wow, great answer. Maybe not specific to this question, but I learned something and it solved my problem.

Comment: +1 Best answer! Thanks for sharing examples for each scenarios (void -> void, args -> void, args -> return)

Answer (score 23):

EDIT: I misread your question and didn't see the bit about wanting to NOP a statement with doing raw memory manipulation. I'm afraid this isn't recommended because, as Raymond Chen says, the GC moves stuff around in memory (hence the 'pinned' keyword in C#). You probably can do it with reflection, but your question suggests you don't have a strong grasp of the CLR. Anyway, back to my original irrelevant answer (where I thought you just wanted information on how to use delegates):

C# isn't a scripting language ;)

Anyway, C# (and the CLR) has "function pointers" - except they're called "delegates" and are strongly typed, which means you need to define the function's signature in addition to the function you want to call.

In your case, you'd have something like this:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {

    Function1();

}

// This is the "type" of the function pointer, known as a "delegate" in .NET.
// An instance of this delegate can point to any function that has the same signature (in this case, any function/method that returns void and accepts a single String argument).
public delegate void FooBarDelegate(String x); 


public static void Function1() {

    // Create a delegate to Function2
    FooBarDelegate functionPointer = new FooBarDelegate( Function2 );

    // call it
    functionPointer("bla");
}

public static void Function2(String x) {

    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: You _can_ nop it (sortove). Create a `Function3` that has no body and change the delegate to `Function3` and have `Main` call the delegate.

Comment: delegate is not a function pointer. There is function pointer and it's called IntPtr. Check: Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate method for example.

Comment: @AdasLesniak That is incorrect, sorry. `IntPtr` represents any pointer value, not just function pointers - and you cannot "call" an `IntPtr` either. The `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` method is to let you pass a raw function-pointer (represented by the `IntPtr`) to other native code. Also note that you cannot easily manipulate `IntPtr` values in C#. My point is that _semantically_ a delegate *is* a (encapsulated) function pointer, but it's _better_ than raw function pointers.

Answer (score 15):

```
public string myFunction(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}

public string functionPointerExample(Func<string,string> myFunction)
{
    return myFunction("Theron");
}
```

Func functionName.. use this to pass methods around. Makes no sense in this context but thats basically how you would use it

Answer (score 5):

Actually there are real function pointers introduced in C# 9

[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code)

From the link:

You can define a function pointer using the `delegate*` syntax. The compiler will call the function using the `calli` instruction rather than instantiating a delegate object and calling `Invoke`

Example for the example in the post:

```cs
static unsafe void function1()
{
    //get function2 pointer
    delegate*<void> ptr = &function2;
    // do something with ptr
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd wish it is useful

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestPointer test = new TestPointer();
        test.function1();
    }
}
class TestPointer
{
    private delegate void fPointer(); // point to every functions that it has void as return value and with no input parameter
    public void function1()
    {
        fPointer point = new fPointer(function2);
        point();
    }
    private void function2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bla");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting a method cannot be done directly from managed code, however the unmanaged .net profiling api can be used to do this. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx) msdn article for example on how to use it.