# Can i access a void from my library to my application that is using it?

Tags: c#

**Can i access from my library to my application that is using it?**

```
public void DoSomething(void MethodName)
{
    MethodName();
}
```

So i know this is a wrong code but can this solved somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754669/c-sharp-function-pointer)

Comment: You can call it directly in your application if it publicly accesses or if it is privet you should respect the encapsulation and call other abstracted function.... maybe Try to look to [Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) to know how to pass a function as an argument ....

Comment: Yes, you instantiate the object containing this method, then call it...