# C# pass methods as parameters

Tags: c#, c++, c, api, pointers

I'm working with an C API in C#. In C Methods are passed as parameters and I'm trying to accomplish the same thing in C#.

in **C** I would call the functions the following way:

```
 LL_SetStatusCb(OnStatusRcv);
 LL_SetScanCb(scanCb);
 LL_Scan();
```

Note that the used methods are defined in the following way:

```
void OnStatusRcv(ll_status_t status)
void scanCb(ll_scan_result_t *result)
```

In C# the methods are defined in the same way but I don't know how I can pass those methods.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550218/how-to-store-a-function-pointer-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1) can help.

Comment: Use [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Func<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) parameters (or their overloads).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# equivalent of function pointers are delegates. You can use Func and Action to pass methods as parameters. Func delegate represents method which takes N arguments and returns value, Action delegate represents void method.

Consider this

```
void (* myFunction)(int parameter)
```

in C# would be

```
Action<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

create ll_scan_result_t and ll_status_t classes.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void ActionRef<T>(ref T item);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ll_status_t _status = new ll_status_t();

        LL_SetStatusCb(_status, OnStatusRcv);

        ll_scan_result_t _scan = new ll_scan_result_t();

        LL_SetScanCb(ref _scan);
    }

    static void LL_SetScanCb(ref ll_scan_result_t status, ActionRef<ll_scan_result_t> getCachedValue)
    {
        //... do something
    }

    static void LL_SetStatusCb(ll_status_t result, Action<ll_status_t> getCachedValue)
    {
        //... do something
    }

    static void OnStatusRcv(ref ll_scan_result_t sresult)
    {
        //... do something
    }

    static void scanCb(ll_status_t s)
    {
        //... do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Func Delegate like below**

```
public class myClass
{

    public bool TestMethod(string input)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public bool Method1(Func<string, bool> methodName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void newMthod()
    {
        Method1(TestMethod);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the equivalent to C/C++ *function pointers* are **delegates**. A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type. When you instantiate a delegate, you can associate its instance with any method that has a compatible signature and return type. You can call the method through the delegate instance.

Here's an example. First, declare a delegate:

```
public delegate void Del(string message);
```

Now, `Del` is a delegate type which can be used to call to any method that returns `void` and accepts an argument of type `string`. Now, let's create some method matching the signature and return type of `Del`:

```
public static void DelegateMethod(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Now, let's create an instance of `Del` and associate it with `DelegateMethod`, like this:

```
Del handler = DelegateMethod;
```

If you want to call `DelegateMethod`, you can do it by:

```
handler("Hello World");
```

Notice that since `Del` is a type, you can do something like this:

```
public static void SomeMethod(Del callback, string callbackParams)
{
    callback(callbackParams);
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
SomeMethod(handler, "Hello World");
```

With that said, there are othes ways of working with delegates. You can use `Func` and `Action` delegates. `Func` is a delegate that points to a method that accepts one or more arguments and returns a value, that is, it doesn't return `void`. `Action` is a delegate that points to a method which in turn accepts one or more arguments but returns no value (returns `void`). In other words, you should use `Action` when your delegate points to a method that returns `void`.

Here's an example of using an `Action` delegate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<string> action = new Action<string>(Display);
    action("Hello!!!");
    Console.Read(); //Prevents from closing the command line right away.
}

static void Display(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Therefore, something like

```
void (* funcPtr)(int) = &someFuncWithAnIntArg;
(*funcPtr)(10);
```

Is equivalent in C# to

```
Action<int> funcPtr = new Action<int>(someFuncWithAnIntArg);
funcPtr(10);
```

And now for a `Func` delegate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<int, double> func = new Func<int, double>(CalculateHra);
    Console.WriteLine(func(50000));
    Console.Read();
}

static double CalculateHra(int basic)
{
    return (double)(basic * .4);
}
```

The syntax for a `Func` delegate accepting an argument and returning a value is like this `Func<TArgument, TOutput>` where `TArgument` is the type of the argument and `TOutput` is the type of returned value. There are many more types of [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) (browse the left tree index) and [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8) (also browse the left tree index) delegates.

And last, but not least, we have the `Predicate` delegates which is typically used to search items in a collection or a set of data. Let's define some boilerplate code to explain:

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, let's try it in:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
   customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, FirstName = "Stack" });
   customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, FirstName = "Overflow" });

   Predicate<Customer> pred = x => x.Id == 1;
   Customer customer = customers.Find(pred);
   Console.WriteLine(customer.FirstName);
   Console.Read();
}
```

The last code snippet will print "Stack". What happened is that the `Predicate` delegate named `prep` was used as a search criteria to search in the list `customers`. Basically, this delegate was run on every element `x` of the list, and when `x.Id == 1` it returns `true`, `false` otherwise. The `x` element where the predicate returned `true` is returned as the result of the `Find` method.